# Function defined, but not actually usable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is user.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null

class User < ActiveRecord::Base      
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_token
  has_secure_password
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, :length => { maximum: 50 }
  valid_email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, :presence   => true,
                    :format     => { with: valid_email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :password,  length: { minimum: 6}

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

I have defined the function `create_remember_token`, but I noticed that in this file I cannot call it. In Rails' console it didn't work either:

```
1.9.2-p290 :002 > User.first.create_remember_token
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: private method `create_remember_token' called for #<User:0x0000010289cda0>
    from /Users/luke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:404:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/luke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:129:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/luke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/luke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/luke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The method you are trying to call is a private method so, you can't call it outside the class you created on. The solution of this problem is to remove the private keyword from the class you defined the method on (User.rb)

Comment: May I ask why you changed the accepted answer? Just curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the error you're getting: `NoMethodError: private method`. Move the method above `private` and you'll be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call private methods only in the class itself, not from outside the class. Move your method above `private`:

```
def create_remember_token
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

private

# Your private methods here
```

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is calling this method in the console, then yes removing it from private will solve the issue. But, I think you definitely want to keep this method private. Is there some other underlying issue? A failing test? The method should work fine as written.